# Looking for missed IDs in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that contains two columns

```
ID | Name
----------------
1  | John
2  | Sam
3  | Peter
6  | Mike
```

It has missed IDs. In this case these are `4` and `5`.

How do I find and insert them together with random names into this table?

**Update**: cursors and temp tables are not allowed. The random name should be 'Name_'+ some random number. Maybe it would be the specified value like 'Abby'. So it doesn't matter.

Comment: When you say random names, do you really mean that you're looking to fill unused slots with data (other names?) Or, are you truly looking to generate random other names?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a little on the RANDOM names for people to assist you in that regard.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, it is virtually never a good idea to insert new values into skipped ids espeicially if they are identities as they likely would be in most databases. Smells like homework.

Comment: Why are cursors and temp tables not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE you can determine the missing IDs as follows

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1, 'John'),(2, 'Sam'),(3,'Peter'),(6, 'Mike')

DECLARE @StartID INT,
        @EndID INT

SELECT  @StartID = MIN(ID),
        @EndID = MAX(ID)
FROM    @Table

;WITH IDS AS (
        SELECT  @StartID IDEntry
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  IDEntry + 1
        FROM    IDS
        WHERE   IDEntry + 1 <= @EndID
)
SELECT  IDS.IDEntry [ID]
FROM    IDS LEFT JOIN
        @Table t    ON  IDS.IDEntry = t.ID
WHERE   t.ID IS NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The option `MAXRECURSION 0` will allow the code to avoid the recursion limit of SQL SERVER

From [Query Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) and [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

> MAXRECURSION number  Specifies the maximum number of recursions
>   allowed for this query. number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and
>   32767. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not specified, the default limit for the server is 100.
>
> When the specified or default number for MAXRECURSION limit is reached
>   during query execution, the query is ended and an error is returned.
>
> Because of this error, all effects of the statement are rolled back.
>   If the statement is a SELECT statement, partial results or no results
>   may be returned. Any partial results returned may not include all rows
>   on recursion levels beyond the specified maximum recursion level.

Generating the *RANDOM* names will largly be affected by the requirements of such a name, and the column type of such a name. What exactly does this random name entail?

Comment: Neat. Makes me want delete my answer. Your answer doesn't do the insert portion of his question, but that's a trivial change to the last few lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a recursive Common Table Expression CTE. Here's an example how:

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(ID) from MyTable
;WITH Numbers(Number) AS 
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 FROM Numbers WHERE Number < @MaxId 
)
SELECT n.Number, 'Random Name'
FROM Numbers n
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t ON n.Number=t.ID
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
```

Here are a couple of articles about CTEs that will be helpful to  [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Start by selecting the highest number in the table (select top 1 id desc), or select max(id), then run a while loop to iterate from 1...max.

See [this article about looping.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3100621)

For each iteration, see if the row exists, and if not, insert into table, with that ID.

Answer (score 2):

I think recursive CTE is a better solution, because it's going to be faster, but here is what worked for me:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]([Id],[Name]) VALUES (1, 'John')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]([Id],[Name]) VALUES (2, 'Sam')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]([Id],[Name]) VALUES (3, 'Peter')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]([Id],[Name]) VALUES (6, 'Mike')
GO

declare @mod int
select @mod = MAX(number)+1 from master..spt_values where [type] = 'P'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
SELECT y.Id,'Name_' + cast(newid() as varchar(45)) Name from
(
    SELECT TOP (select MAX(Id) from [dbo].[TestTable]) x.Id from
    (
        SELECT 
        t1.number*@mod + t2.number Id
        FROM master..spt_values t1
        CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
        WHERE t1.[type] = 'P' and t2.[type] = 'P'
    ) x
    WHERE x.Id > 0 
    ORDER BY x.Id
) y
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TestTable] on [TestTable].Id = y.Id
where [TestTable].Id IS NULL
GO

select * from [dbo].[TestTable]
order by Id
GO
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c7b/18

Answer (score -2):

It's actually very simple :

Create a table called #All_numbers which should contain all the natural number in the range that you are looking for.

#list is a table containing your data

```
select a.num as missing_number ,
       'Random_Name' + convert(varchar, a.num) 
from #All_numbers a left outer join #list l on a.num = l.Id
where l.id is null
```